# Crossdomain.xml vulnerabilities

Tags: web-application, crossdomain

```
<cross-domain-policy>
 <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
 <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I would like to ask two questions:

1. Is this crossdomain.xml vulnerable (the file is placed on the root of the host e.g. www.example.com/crossdomain.xml)?
2. How I can exploit or test similar files?

Comment: I'm sure you've seen this because it's from a quick google but http://sethsec.blogspot.com/2014/03/exploiting-misconfigured-crossdomainxml.html looks like the most comprehensive resource for exploiting this type of vulnerability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This crossdomain.xml policy file revokes all protection that the [Same Origin Policy](https://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2) provides.

I use the [crossdomain proof of concept tool](https://thehackerblog.com/crossdomain-xml-proof-of-concept-tool/),  which has a [simple interface to test SOP bypasses](https://thehackerblog.com/crossdomain-xml-proof-of-concept-tool/).

Comment: Thanks. So this particular file is vulnerable right?

Comment: @Michal Koczwara Without a shadow of a doubt. 100% textbook issue right here, all sources will confirm that the SOP has been intentionally disabled. It really doesn't get clearer than this.

Comment: So basically an attacker can send requests to the target from any random domains here: <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/> but not sure what is this ? <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>

Comment: `<allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>` is allow from all.