# Does the 'Relational' Foundation of Database Theory enable 'Ashley Madison'-like attacks?

Tags: sql-injection, databases

Again and again hackers use SQL injection to get information from the backend database. Is it fair to say because a relational database by its nature has all the links within the data sets (e.g., 1-to-1, 1-to-* and so on), therefore it enables a user with any form of access to illegally access everything, either in theory or practice?

Comment: The amount of other information compromised in the Ashley Madison attack (internal documents, network diagrams) makes it tremendously unlikely that it was a SQL injection attack.

Comment: I wrote an article about possible attack vector regarding ashleymadison hack. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ashleymadisoncom-so-secure-michal-koczwara?trk=pulse_spock-articles

Comment: @MichalKoczwara you also wrote about it here: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/97293/6253

Comment: @shroeder no this is a different crossdomain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How data is related or not within the database has nothing to do with SQLi. Flat files, NoSQL, etc. will not affect the ability for a user to perform unauthorized access to data.

SQLi is about unsecured direct access to the database (in whatever form that is), resulting in a user manipulating that access in order to obtain data without the expected authorization.

Comment: Authentication on [NoSQL](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2884320/security/3-security-pain-points-nosql.html) seems to be worse partially due to default authentication being [remarkably trusting](http://www.securityweek.com/big-data-smaller-problems-configuring-kerberos-authentication-hadoop).

Comment: yeah - I wasn't going to poke holes in the inherent security of the various database technologies because the question was more about SQLi in general.